# How do i change layout of the same activity using AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to change the layout whenever a database connection is unsuccessful.

I was thinking of executing `setContentView(R.layout.no_connection);`
whenever an exception is thrown from `doInBackground();` method, but it is not working, my app crashes.

```
class Connect extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String> {

        private Exception exception;

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String result = "";

        public Connect(TextView tv) {
            this.tv = tv;
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try {

               // StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
               // StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                final String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.4:3308/demo"; //192.168.43.137:3308
                final String user = "Vishal"; //testUser
                String pass = "password"; //test

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass); //(urls[0], urls[1], urls[2])

                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from user_info");
                ResultSetMetaData rand = rs.getMetaData();

                while(rs.next()){
                    result  += rs.getInt(1)+"  " + rs.getString(2)+"  "  + rs.getString(3)+"\n " ;
                }
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connection Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //result = "Database Connection Success\n";
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return result;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.exception = e;


                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return e.toString();
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {
            // TODO: check this.exception
            // TODO: do something with the feed
            if(result == null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Result null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            if(feed == null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "feed null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
            tv.setText(feed);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connection Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }

    ;
```

I call it in the main UI thread using `abc = new Connect(tv).execute(url).toString();`
Is there any better way to do it?Please suggest, I'm a noobie.

Comment: Calling `setContentView` is usually a poor idea after the first instance. Use Fragments instead

Comment: If your application crashes, please [edit] your question to include the logcat

Comment: Please provide code

Comment: @ cricket_007 i  definitely use fragments if layout to is to be changed but why `setContentView ` is poor idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should update your UI this way:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // here update UI methods
    }
};
runOnUiThread(r);
```

Comment: It's not my question... You should comment above before answering

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use AsynkTask for updating your view, you should do it in method onPostExecute(), because method [doInBackGround performed in other thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I want to change the layout only when internet connection fails, I check that in doInBackground() , what code should be put where to do so??

Comment: How you check internet connection?